# Are questions tagged [status-completed] closed/locked?

Tags: support, tags, closed-questions, locked-questions

Does the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag effectively close / lock a question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't. A locked question is a question that cannot be voted, and answered anymore. The tag is used from moderators, and developers to mark the task reported in the question as completed.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. You can still add an answer to questions tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: @genesis you're welcome! :)